# how to assign server control a value for jquery side using registerclientscriptblock

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've got a hidden field with `runat=server` set to it.  It's ID is hdnIsSaved.  How do I use the `scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock` to set a field that has `runat='server'` a value?

I tried this:

`ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "SetSaved", "$('#<%= hdnIsSaved.ClientID %>').val('1');", true);`

I dont think I have the syntax right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "SetSaved", 
   "$('" +  hdnIsSaved.ClientID + "').val('1');", true);
```

Instead of writing the "client-side to server-side grabbing of the ID", I just get the ID from the control directly in the code-behind.  If this doesn't work, try wrapping this script in `$(document).ready(function() { .. });` or the shorter `$(function() { .. });` syntax.

Comment: I don't know if you care or not, but if you are setting DBIDs in the client, you may want to Hash it so things are less discoverable.